# object returned from NSJSONSerialization can vary

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

Is the following statement correct, or am I missing something?

You have to check the return object of `NSJSONSerialization` to see if it is a dictionary or an array - you can have

```
data = {"name":"joe", "age":"young"}
// NSJSONSerialization returns a dictionary
```

and

```
data = {{"name":"joe", "age":"young"},
    {"name":"fred", "age":"not so young"}}
// returns an array
```

Each type has a different access method which breaks if used on the wrong one. 
For example:

```
NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [json objectAtIndex:i];
// will break if json is a dictionary
```

so you have to do something like -

```
  id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if ([jsonObjects isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        NSLog(@"yes we got an Array"); // cycle thru the array elements
    else if ([jsonObjects isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
         NSLog(@"yes we got an dictionary"); // cycle thru the dictionary elements
    else
          NSLog(@"neither array nor dictionary!");
```

I had a good look thru stack overflow and Apple documentation and other places and could not find any direct confirmation of the above.

Comment: You didn't mention what problem was going on with your code.

Comment: The problem is if you get a dictionary back and use an array method to access it an exception is thrown. I think you need to check the return object type to fix this, but would like confirmation that this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just asking if this is correct or not, yes it is the safe way to process `jsonObjects`. It's also how you would do it with other API that returns `id`.

Comment: ok - thanks for this - there are quite a few questions on use of NSJSONSerialization and not checking the return type (or always assuming it is not variable) is/was (for me anyway) a subtle gotcha. The purpose of this post was to confirm and clarify.